# How to find height and width of a rectangle in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

How can I find the width and height of a rectangle drawn with the function `cvRectangle` with the following parameters?

```
cvRectangle( input1, cvPoint(200,178), cvPoint(190,110),color ,1, 8 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You set the parameters, so calculating width and height should be trivial, shouldn't it? `width = (200-190)` and `height = (178-110)`. But, as @bubble suggests, since you're most likely dealing with pixels, don't forget to add 1, resulting in `(200 - 190) + 1` for width and `(178 - 110) + 1` for height.

Or do you expect [`cvRectangle`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/drawing_functions.html) to give you some rectangle "object" you can get these values from? It doesn't.

Comment: isn't it (200 - 190) + 1 for width and (178 - 110) + 1 for height

Comment: @bubble Ah, in terms of pixel width you mean? Then, yes.

Comment: Any kind of width it may be. Realistically speaking a pixel isnt a infinitesimal point. Its a rectangle. Lighting up one pixel means lighting up one such rectangle of defined length. "a" no of pixels lighted up equals a X pixel width.

Comment: @bubble That's what I was getting at. I agreed with you. :)